# How to define variable name in Jupyter notebook through interactive widget (python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I need the following functionality:

```
#what do you want to name the processed file?
(widget here)

filename=(widget input string)
```

I did not find any easy examples in the widget documentation or other searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use standard python `input()`

```
text = input("Your input: ")
print(text)
```

or use the `ipywidgets` module

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
text = widgets.Text(placeholder='Your input')
display(text)

def print_input(sender):
    print(text.value)

text.on_submit(print_input)
```

also see the docs for the `ipywidgets` module [here](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).